# Excel horizontal axis values irregular and ugly

Tags: excel, excel-2010

The image shows a chart with time vs temp and humidity data from a high-powered rocket launch (it hit about 7000 ft at the highest point, and then slowly parachuted down).  There are about 4000 data points here.  What I want to fix is the ugly horizontal axis numbers.  How do I get them to display as fixed interval numbers? I think tens would do nicely.

[image]

Comment: Right-click the axis, select "Format Axis" and play around with the options. You can set the intervals to "Auto" or manually set them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the chart type.

A **line chart** will show the X axis as a category axis, and each value will be a marker on the chart. If the X values are dates, a line chart can accommodate that (i.e. put in spaces for missing days).

If the X axis is not based on date values, it will be treated as a category axis.

A category axis will show each category. If there are too many categories to plot, every nth category label will be omitted.

You can also use an YX Scatter chart to plot your data. For this to work, the data for both the Y and the X axis need to be numeric.

The X axis of an XY chart can be formatted to display markers at specific data points.

Comment: Ahh, okay, I see.  Scatter plot is the solution.  The line chart won't work.  Thank you so much.